# jquery quickpager add ellipse_text

Tags: jquery

I am using the following quickpager with next and prev buttons :

```
(function($) {

$.fn.quickPager = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        pageSize: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        holder: null,
        pagerLocation: "after"
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);   

    return this.each(function() {


        var selector = $(this); 
        var pageCounter = 1;
        var x = 0;
        var nextLink = '<li><a id="nextLink" href="#">Next</a></li>';
        var prevLink = '<li><a id="prevLink" href="#">Prev</a></li>';



        if( selector.parent("div.simplePagerContainer").length == 0 ) {
            selector.wrap("<div class='simplePagerContainer'></div>");
        }

        selector.parents(".simplePagerContainer").find("ul.simplePagerNav").remove();

        selector.children().each(function(i){ 
            $(this)[0].className = $(this)[0].className.replace(/\bsimplePagerPage.*?\b/g, '');
            if(!$(this).is(":hidden")) {
                if(x < pageCounter*options.pageSize && x >= (pageCounter-1)*options.pageSize) {
                    $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage"+pageCounter);

                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage"+(pageCounter+1));
                    pageCounter ++;
                }   
                x++;
            }
        });       


        // show/hide the appropriate regions 
        selector.children().hide();
        selector.children(".simplePagerPage"+options.currentPage).show();

        if(pageCounter <= 1) {
          return;
        }

        //Build pager navigation
        var pageNav = "<ul class='simplePagerNav'>";
        $(".simplePagerNav").prepend(prevLink).append(nextLink);  
        for (i=1;i<=pageCounter;i++){
            if (i==0) {

            }
            if (i==options.currentPage) {
                pageNav += "<li class='currentPage simplePageNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>"; 
            }
            else {
                pageNav += "<li class='simplePageNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>";
            }
        }

        pageNav += "</ul>";

        if(!options.holder) {
            switch(options.pagerLocation)
            {
            case "before":
                selector.before(pageNav);
            break;
            case "both":
                selector.before(pageNav);
                selector.after(pageNav);
            break;
            default:
                selector.after(pageNav);
            }
        }
        else {
            $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
        }

        //pager navigation behaviour
        selector.parent().find(".simplePagerNav a").click(function() {

            //grab the REL attribute 
            var clickedLink = $(this).attr("rel");
            options.currentPage = clickedLink;

            if(options.holder) {
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("li.currentPage").removeClass("currentPage");
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("currentPage");
            }
            else {
                //remove current current (!) page
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".simplePagerContainer").find("li.currentPage").removeClass("currentPage");
                //Add current page highlighting
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".simplePagerContainer").find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("currentPage");
            }

            //hide and show relevant links
            selector.children().hide();         
            selector.find(".simplePagerPage"+clickedLink).show();

            return false;
        });                

// add previous link        
$("#prevLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li.currentPage").prev("li[class^=simplePageNav]").find("a").click();
});

      // add next link
      $("#nextLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li.currentPage").next("li[class^=simplePageNav]").find("a").click();
});

    });



}
})(jQuery);
```

Now I want to have it like this :  prev 1234 ... 567 next  how would you add this to the quickpager?

See for an example the following : http://tutorials.ajaxmasters.com/pagination-demo/

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, have n't you checked this. [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/GCJ5H/)

Comment: Have you checked the ajaxmasters link? Your link it's not quite the same. There are no dots between the numbers and numbers also don't dissapear or reappear like in the url I posted.

Now I have this :S  http://jsfiddle.net/mm5kh/30/